# calculate the median across several vectors

Tags: r, median

I need to calculate the median of `ROE1`, `ROE2` and `ROE3`. But, to calculate each median I have to include all the rows with the same `Datum` and same `Ind` categories. For instance, to calculate the median of the second row, I have to include the row 2 and 3, because I have the same `Datum` and `Ind` in the row 2 and 3. I am trying to use the loop function `apply`, but I don´t know how I can include this condition.

It is like a conditional median.

Thank you very much for your attention.

Here, it is the example:

```
Datum   Ind ROE1    ROE2    ROE3
 95     45  NA      6       13
 95     45  18      25      28
 95     50  10      15      20
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(Median = median(unlist(.SD), na.rm = TRUE)), by = list(Datum, Ind)]
#    Datum Ind Median
# 1:    95  45     18
# 2:    95  50     15
```

Another option is to tidy up the data first using `melt`

```
melt(setDT(df), id.vars = c("Datum", "Ind"))[, 
                  list(Median = median(value, na.rm = TRUE)), 
                  by = list(Datum, Ind)]

#    Datum Ind Median
# 1:    95  45     18
# 2:    95  50     15
```

---

Or if you an Hadleyverse fan, could also do

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  gather(Variable, value, -(Datum:Ind))%>%
  group_by(Datum, Ind) %>%
  summarise(Median = median(value, na.rm = TRUE))

# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
# Groups: Datum
# 
#   Datum Ind Median
# 1    95  45     18
# 2    95  50     15
```

Comment: Dear David Arenburg,
thank you very much for your answer.

All of them worked on my example, but unfortunately it is not in my original data.

When I use the function : setDT(df)...

The result of the median is not matching the categories. Maybe it´s because I have categories just with NA values. When I try subset just rows without NA values the result of the median is wrong.

Do you have any suggestion?

The other solutions I have this error. Column 1 of result for group 5 is type 'double' but expecting type 'character'. Column types must be consistent for each group.)

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example when this isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

another option, with base R, you can do:

```
med_by <- aggregate(df, by=list(df$Datum, df$Ind), median, na.rm=T)[, -(1:2)]  
data.frame(med_by[, 1:2], Median=apply(med_by[, grepl("ROE", colnames(med_by))], 1, median))

#   Datum Ind Median
# 1    95  45     18
# 2    95  50     15
```